# The argument type 'RxInt' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'

Tags: flutter, dart, integer, flutter-getx

I define 2 RxInt variable in controller class. But when I was calculate sum of two number then I got error: The argument type 'RxInt' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'. Bellow my code:

```
class LogicController extends GetxController {
  RxInt number = 0.obs;
  RxInt thirdNumber = 0.obs;

  void count() {
    number++;
  }

  void thirdNumberCount() {
    thirdNumber++;
  }

  addTwoNumber() {
    return  number + thirdNumber; // error 
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `addTwoNumber` method? It does not specify any return value so do you want to return `RxInt` or `int`? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
return  number.value + thirdNumber.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.value` or `.toInt()` on your RxInt values